# Cufon Loading But Not Displaying

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, cufon

Test case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cufon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/font.font.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Text</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Cufon.replace('h1');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

where "cufon.js" is the latest version (same result with minimized version from the main site and non-minimized version from GitHub), and "font.font.js" is a generated font from cufon's website subset to Latin.

There are no HTTP, HTML, CSS, or JS errors reported by the browser, and yet no VML is generated in IE 8, FF 3.6, or Safari 5. Generated output does have `<html class="cufon-active cufon-ready">` and Cufon inline styles, but that's it.

I've also tried, to no avail:

- Switching where the scripts appear (before `</head>` and before `</body>`)
- Calling jQuery before Cufon
- Manually declaring the font-family specified in font.font.js using inline CSS
- Changing the `DOCTYPE` from HTML5 to  XHTML 1.1 or HTML 4.01 Strict

Comment: Do you not have to specify the registered font-name that you want replace with?

Comment: Your test case works fine for me when I test using a font file I'd already generated and knew to be working, and the syntax looks fine.  Are you sure the font file is being loaded and is properly referenced, and that it contains the necessary glyphs? This could be a bug re: generating a Cufon version of a specific font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hadn't listed localhost as an authorized domain. Silly me.

Answer (score 1):

I've always included the fontFamily name:

```
Cufon.replace('#search-button', { fontFamily: 'Futura', hover: true });
```